# QlikSense: Pick function

Tags: qliksense

I'm attempting something very simple. I have created a variable with values 1-4, with the intention of using this variable to select the appropriate datetime field depending on variable chosen:

[image]

This is what I have as the expression in my column:

[image]

When I test it by clicking 'Done editing', the changing the variable does not change the column's output. Does this function not do what I thought it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should definitely work. Make sure you're setting it up correctly:

Make sure your Variable Input object is using the correct variable:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense Variable Input properties]

It looks like all of the `value`s for your variable options are numeric which is correct but maybe doublecheck to make sure.

If you continue to have issues, you could try using [dollar-sign expansion](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/dollar-sign-expansion-using-variable.htm) to access the value of the variable directly in the expression, like so:

```
=Pick( $(vT1) , name, rating, released)
```

It *should* work the way you're doing it though:

[image: Screen recording of Qlik Sense Variable Input]

Comment: The dollar sign expansion did the trick, thank you so much!